# Scoping issues with eval variables in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I seem to have scoping issues with this script when running it through react, I am trying to create a variable that contains a string to its path for every file within a specified folder. This code works just fine through the node console, however these variables seem give me `error    'imgChar' is not defined` when using it in a react environment.

```
const fs = require('fs');
function importFiles(filepath, prefix) {
  fs.readdir(filepath, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
      var doc = file
      var char = /.+(?=\.\w+)/.exec(file);
      if (char !== null) {
        eval(prefix + char + " = " + "'" + String(filepath + doc) + "'");
      }
    });
  })
}
importFiles('../public/img/', 'img');
```

P.S. I also realise `eval()` may not be a smart and secure way to implement this so any suggestion on a smarter implementation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want a variable for every file? Wouldn't a hash or something be a better approach?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I am mostly seeking to have files such as images to be predeclared.

Comment: How would you use them? E.g., you'd have to change your code if the files changed anyway. It's not immediately clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Why not variable that is array of filenames?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am trying to have files such as images be variables so I do not have to redundantly declare the filepatch each time I source them in a div.